# JMeter WebDriver Sampler don't have javascript for script language

Tags: javascript, jmeter

Anyone know why my JMeter "jc@gc-WebDriver Sampler" don't have the javascript for default Script Language?
I am using JMeter-5.4.1 and the available languages is beanshell, java, groovy, jexl2 & jexl. Please kindly provide the solution. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3FA0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nashorn engine which provided JavaScript execution capabilities has been [removed from Java](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) so the options are in:

1. Downgrade to the Java version where the feature is there (the lowest Java version which can run JMeter is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/))
2. Use [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) which has this JavaScript engine
3. Consider using a different language for scripting, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) as it provides [maximum performance comparing to other options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).